# Ascoli-Arzela theorem: Hausdorff assumption needed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Theorem 4.43 is Folland's *Real Analysis* is

> **Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem I**. Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. If $\mathscr{F}$ is an equicontinuous, pointwise bounded subset of
>   $C(X)$, then $\mathscr{F}$ is totally bounded in the uniform metric,
>   and the closure of $\mathscr{F}$ in $C(X)$ is compact.

I could not understand where the assumption that $X$ is Hausdorff is used in the proof. Is this assumption necessary?

Comment: I'd guess the assumption is not neccessary, but you don't gain much by dropping it since, if $X$ a noncompact Hausdorff space, then $C(X) \cong C(X')$ where $X'$ is compact Hausdorff by Gelfand duality. Moreover, I think $X'$ is some reasonable quotient of $X$ and the isomorphism $C(X) \cong C(X')$ is induced by this quotient mapping.